# Python or command line utility - sort and filter file?

Tags: python, command-line, text-processing

Given data of the form:

```
a b 1.1
c d 2.3
b a 1.1
```

Is it possible to sort such a file based on the thired column and remove lines where the entry in the third column is duplicated, such that the output will be:

```
a b 1.1
c d 2.3
```

or,

```
c d 2.3
b a 1.1
```

.

I am capable of using only python, R or command line utilities to perform this task on a set of very large files.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you decide which of the "1.1" rows to discard?

Comment: It doesn't matter which is discarded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unix `sort` should be able to do the work for you:

```
cat file | sort -u -k3,3n
a b 1.1
c d 2.3
```

```
cat file | sort -u -k3,3rn
c d 2.3
a b 1.1
```

Comment: @Dominik: how does it _not_ help?

Comment: @Dominik: The OP showed two sample outputs, one with each sort direction, and the OP has said that the duplicate line discarded does not matter. I think I've demonstrated what the OP is asking for.

Comment: It answers the question perfectly. It sorts and drops duplicates...+1

Comment: @Dominik: did not implement, OP said it doesn't matter

Comment: @ MattH - elegant and extremely fast. I learned something new. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
f = open('text.txt','rb')
filter = []
rows = []
for line in f:
    line = line.replace('\r\n','')
    data = line.split(' ')
    if len(data) >= 3:
        if not data[2] in filter:
            filter.append(data[2])
            rows.append(data)
f.close()

f = open('output.txt','wb')
for row in rows:
    f.write(row[0] + ' ' + row[1] + ' ' + row[2] + '\r\n')
f.close()
```